# Split Json data into multiple data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'url',
           data: val,
           async: false,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (max) {
               console.log(max.origin);
           }
       });
```

Then i am getting an output which is

```
["test,origin"]
```

I want to split it like .

```
 test
 origin
```

Please suggest me .

Much appreciated

Comment: Are you getting like ["test,origin"]   or ["test","origin"] ?

Comment: If you could add your `max` json object structure to your question that would be helpful.

Comment: So is this a whole string like `'["test,origin"]'`?

Answer (score 1):

`max.origin[0].split(",")[0]` will give you `test`

`max.origin[0].split(",")[1]` will give you `origin`

Comment: Doesn't look like they are.. like Sai sudhakar's comment says, it depends if the output is ["test,origin"] or ["test","origin"]

Answer (score 1):

If your returned value of max.origin really is `["test,origin"]`, you have to do something like this

```
var data = max.origin[0].split(',');
```

so that `data` will contain a list of the elements that are comma-separated. However, if your `max.origin` is in the form of `["test", "origin"]`, you can simply select each/all items by going through a for-loop and (optionally) print them out:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= max.origin.length; i++) {
  console.log(max.origin[i]);
}
```

If you know that you only get the two elements (test and origin) each time, @void's answer is a good approach.

Comment: No what he is getting is a `string` not an `array`

Comment: Yes, but the string is within an array of length 1.